# Angular 2: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: javascript, php, json, angular

I am using Angular 2 and I want to send the json data to a php file. When I try to send the data using the post request, it says "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data". When I look at the network tab it says status 200, so it sent it. I am not sure what I am doing wrong, but I would appreciate if someone could look this over.

**Here is the data service I am using for the post request**

```
sendData(data): Observable<Object>{
 let url = "test.php";
 let encoded_data = JSON.stringify({data});
 console.log('encoded', encoded_data);
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.post(url, encoded_data).map(
        (res: Response) => res.json() || {}
    );
}
```

**I use it in my component like this.**

```
sendDatatoServer(){
  this.dataService.sendData(this.data)
     .subscribe(
        data => {
           console.log('the data', data);
        },
       (err) => console.log(err),
       () => console.log("data success!!")
      );
 }
```

**My json data looks somewhat like this when it is stringified.**

```
{"data": [{"title": "sometext" }, {"title": "sometext" }]}
```

**Here is the test.php file I have so far. I am not sure if this is correct or not, but it doesnt send any response.**

```
<?php


header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

 $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
 $request = json_decode($postdata);

 echo $request;
```

Comment: `$request` is an object, what do you expect `echo $request;` to display?

Comment: @Barmar I tried to echo the keys, but I keep getting an error.

Comment: The issue is not the request, but the response. You map your response to res.json(), which will throw the parsing error, when for example the response contains html. This can easily happen when your webserver returns an exception.

Comment: The client is expecting the response to be JSON. You can't just echo the keys, you need to echo a JSON string. `echo json_encode($request);`.

Comment: @Barmar I understand what you mean. I added the json_encode and the parse error disappears. When I try to access the keys like `echo json_encode($request->title)`, I get the syntax error in the console.

Comment: What do you see when you view the response in the Network tab of Developer Tools?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem seems to be entirely on PHP side, I think. Just wondering about the following:

```
let encoded_data = JSON.stringify({data});
```

Should you really have the curly brackets there? Well, the important thing is that if it the stringified JSON looks like:

```
{"data": [{"title": "sometext" }, {"title": "sometext" }]}
```

it should all be good.

As mentioned in the comments, you need to json_encode your data on the PHP side:

```
echo json_encode($request);
```

In the comment you said you wanted to access the title like so:

```
echo json_encode($request->title)
```

It's not possible, which title do you mean? Your json is an object that contains an array, so to access e.g the first title, you would have to do the following:

```
echo json_encode($request->data[0]->title);
```

Apart from this, the rest of your code looks fine, so this should work :)

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. This is really helpful. I still get the error, but the data does show up in my database. So thats good.

Comment: What error are you getting and where? I actually tried this and it worked fine.

Comment: The error I get from the console. Its weird though. `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`  Its weird because it was just working, then all of a sudden, it throws this error.

Comment: I tried with your exact code and it worked for me. Try to hardcode the object first, and see if that works, so instead of `let encoded_data = JSON.stringify({data});` do: `JSON.stringify({ "data": [{ "title": "sometext" }, { "title": "sometext" }] })` so you'll know if you have the error there.